# Why is this appearing: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I read the other answers on here but nothing has worked. The issue is if the user enters an incorrect password I get this error (username is fine):

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Stack trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Login.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Michelle\Desktop\COMF510_65300_HS_task_2\Login.aspx.cs:31
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9628614
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

the login.aspx.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection myDB = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LoginConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        myDB.Open();
        string checkUser = "select count (*) from users where username = '"+txtUserName.Text+"'";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkUser, myDB);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        myDB.Close();

        if (temp == 1)
        {
            myDB.Open();
            string checkPassWord = "select password from users where password = '" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand passCom = new SqlCommand(checkPassWord, myDB);
            string pass = passCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ","");
            if(pass == txtPassword.Text)
            {
                Session["New"] = txtUserName.Text;
                Response.Redirect("EmpWelcome.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Incorrect details!  Please try again.");// if password is incorrect
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Incorrect details!  Please try again."); // if username is incorrect
        }
    }
}
```

the source error:

Line 31: string pass = passCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ","");

I'm sure it is an easy fix for experts but I am pretty new in C#. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Either `passComm` or the result of `ExecuteScalar` is `null`.

Comment: @ D Gibbs Like i have said I already checked out that post.  I am new so the extensive explanation is not newbie friendly! A simple explanation and an example goes a long way. Thanks for your input.

Comment: `int temp= Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());`
try this

Comment: `string pass = passCom.ExecuteScalar() ?? string.empty;`
Replace your line 31 with this code.

Comment: `string pass = string.Empty;
            var exec = passCom.ExecuteScalar();
            if (exec !=null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(exec.ToString()))
            {
                pass = exec.ToString();
                pass.Replace(" ", "");

                if (pass == txtPassword.Text)\{Session["New"] = txtUserName.Text;
Response.Redirect("EmpWelcome.aspx");
 }
 else
{
                    Response.Write("Incorrect details!  Please try again.");
}}`

Comment: By the way, your code has a fatal flaw (other than SQL injection attacks), since you don't validate the user name and password **together**, if you enter *any* valid user and *any* valid password (even one from another user), your code will validate the user and let them through.

Comment: Thats ok for now as it is a task and wont go live. But thank you for the input :)

Answer (score 1):

`com.ExecuteScalar()` is null (no results were found)

Try following code (and also don't remember dispose db objects by `using` constructions).

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection myDB = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LoginConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        myDB.Open();
        string passwordObject = "select password from users where username = '" + txtUserName.Text + "'";
        using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(passwordObject, myDB))
        {
            var res = com.ExecuteScalar();
            if (res != null)
            {
                string checkPassWord = passwordObject as string;
                if (txtPassword.Text == checkPassWord)
                {
                    Session["New"] = txtUserName.Text;
                    Response.Redirect("EmpWelcome.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("Incorrect details!  Please try again.");// if password is incorrect
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Incorrect details!  Please try again."); // if username is incorrect
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example fixes one *potential* problem, but not the line he's actually having problems with, the password one...

Comment: `select password from users where password='<password>'` is very strange construction. I can't understand it.

Comment: Thats not the line with the problem, this one is: `string pass = passCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ", "");`

Comment: if i enter the correct username and password it works fine. If i enter the wrong password it does that above error! so weird!!

Comment: @user3515765, try updated code. I can't test, but I think it should work.

Comment: @ General- Doomer thank you so much. Works prefect :) Perhaps i need to name my variables/objects better! Again thank you for your time.

Comment: @General-Doomer after logging in with the correct details it is displaying the error message incorrect details! opps!

Comment: What says debug? What values of `txtPassword.Text` and `checkPassWord` ?

Comment: ok so far its not reaching the if statement : if (txtPassword.Text == checkPassWord)    it just skips to else

Comment: checkPassWord = password from users where username = 'Shell'

Comment: txtPassword = abcd (which is the password)